# Why is it special for a field extension to be both normal and separable?

Tags: galois-theory

So I reading about Galois theory and it says that a Galois extension is an algebraic extension that is both normal and separable. But why is it special for an extension to have these two properties. It must be special enough that we give it the name Galois...

So from I can tell, if an extension $K/k$ is galois, then $\alpha \in K$ has an irreducible minimal polynomial in $k[X], m_\alpha.$ Hence, $m_\alpha$ either splits or doesn't in $K[X].$ And if it does split, it splits into distinct linear factors. Why is this 'good' or why do we study it? Will I find out as I keep reading?

Comment: Yes, keep reading. Galois extensions have very nice properties.

Answer (score 0):

A better definition is that $K/F$ is normal if for every homomorphism $f:K\to\overline{F}$ (algebraic closure) the image of $K$ lies in $K$.
Another definition is 
$$|Aut(K/F)|=[K:F].$$ These are equivalent to your definition. Basically galois extensions have automorphism groups that reflect their structure.

Comment: Your first condition is a definition of "normal", not "Galois".

Comment: @EricWofsey Good point.